# Basic Circuit AND,OR and NOT with 3 LED

Tags: integrated-circuit, breadboard

I just started my course in logic design and digital computer circuit
how can you create a circuit with AND, OR and NOT connecting it to 3 LED and connects to a DIP?
I have trouble understanding this topic while it's just basics, so I appreciate the help!

Comment: What do you want the circuit to do? Start with that, then figure out what parts you'll use to build it.

Comment: What component is the DIP? This question needs a bit of work, it's pretty unclear at present ;-)

Comment: This question is lacking information required to answer it. We have to guess at your intention, we need more clarity on what you are trying to get the circuit to do. You do not have to write how to do it, but what are the LEDs doing, what do you mean by DIP?

Answer (score 2):

I'll presume that by "DIP" you mean a set of (2) DIP switches, not a dip sauce.

Furthermore I guess you have basic logic building blocks, like from the TTL series (74LSxx) or HCMOS (74HCxx). Connect the DIP switches to the inputs of each of the different gates. For the [74HC08](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT08.pdf) quad AND gate, for instance, you can use the first gate, which has its inputs connected to pins 1  and 2, and the output to pin 3. You can find that in figures 1 and 2 in the datasheet. If you use HCMOS parts all unused inputs should be connected to either ground or Vcc.

Connect the switches between Vcc (positive supply) and inputs, and add a pair of 10 kΩ resistors between the inputs and ground. If a switch is open that input will be made low by the resistor. If you close the switch, that will make the input high.

Now connect a LED with a 220 Ω resistor between the output (pin 3) and ground. Try all combinations of the switches and observe the LED for each of them, and write this down in a table:

```
SW1  SW2    LED
off  off     ?
off  on      ?
on   off     ?
on   on      ?
```

So you fill out the question marks. Such a table is called a **truth table**, and it represents the behavior of the gate. Make such a truth table for the AND gate, another one for the OR gate, and finally one for the NOT gate.